# gitlab-runner: Add ssh key when executing locally

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run a `ci` pipeline locally for debugging purposes, via `docker` executor, by running:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker <job_name>
```

At some point in time, it needs to clone a private `git` repo.

I am using the typical [recipe](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor) suggested by gitlab.

```
variables:
    MY_PRIVATE_KEY: <my_private_key>

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$MY_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

However, when trying to add the key to the agent:

```
$ ssh-add <(echo "$MY_PRIVATE_KEY")
Enter passphrase for /dev/fd/63: Running after script...
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
FATAL: exit code 1
```

I am positive I do not have a `passphrase` on my key...

Comment: I have the same issue, it could be more efficient this way to build and test locally however i found this one useful link about running jobs and pipeline locally but this is not yet available maybe in the near future but hopefully as soon as possible. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2797

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much how to debug the git ci locally. Personally I didn't needed it and if it's about ssh and it's keys it's not helping much because the handling of keys are differently.

Mind two things:

1. Don't store your private key in gitlab repository (as a file). Don't put it into the ci script. Use the gitlab feature: mask variables: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables
2. You might run into some problems storing the private key, because gitlab has certain constrains regarding the variable format. One working solution is to base64 the password. Checkout this issue to learn about that: [GITLAB CI Error loading key "/dev/fd/63": invalid format ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223622/gitlab-ci-error-loading-key-dev-fd-63-invalid-format-error-job-failed-exit/55523151#55523151)

Your .gitlab.yml might look like this. Depending which image you use, you have to install the ssh-agent (first line in the before_script section).

```sh
deploy:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
  script:
    - ssh -t user@host "remote command && other command on remote"
```

The `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is **not** defined in this script but as a masked variable. See [GitLab CI/CD environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the private key content is set right?

Try adding a `echo $MY_PRIVATE_KEY` before the `ssh-add`

Also; I suggest injecting it through [Gitlab CI/CD secrets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html) instead of in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Comment: I would but I want a solution for running it **locally**, via `gitlab-runner exec docker my_job_name`

Comment: I see some differences with the recipe page as you link in the OP, have you tried implementing it exactly as they do?

Comment: Τhe weird thing is that on the `gitlab-runner` (i.e. the remote machine) it runs ok; it just doesn't execute locally when I type the above command in my cmd...

Comment: My user (`pkaramol`)...The variable `MY_PRIVATE_KEY` has my rsa private key.

Comment: You could try to use `sudo`, it could be a permission thing

Answer (score -2):

I was able to manage this problem, in my case it is because of a wrong private key format.

Here is what my `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

```
variables:
  MY_PRIVATE_KEY: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    UYADFAIBAAKCAgEAtn4G7FlPz5IAqbxA0MTO8ip.........................
    yo9Gob/UXA3RFpbTMPItenz6r9D9dn..................................
    .................................
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

before_script:
  - apt-get update -y
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$MY_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

If the `ssh-add <(echo "$MY_PRIVATE_KEY")` won't work replace it to:

```
- echo -n "$MY_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
```

For me this workaround is working.

Comment: Never ever put a private key into the ci script. Use the gitlab variables and mask them: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

Comment: @stackovermat you are right, we are already using variables. The explicit declaration of the `MY_PRIVATE_KEY` was just to emphasize the wrong format for clarification.