# GITLAB CI Error loading key "/dev/fd/63": invalid format ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: gitlab-ci

Here is my code  giltlab-ci.yml :

```
 before_script:
  ##
  ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
  ##
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

  ##
  ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  ##
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  ##
  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  ## without extra base64 encoding.
  ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  ##
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  #- echo -n "$PROJECT_SSH_KEY" | ssh-add - >/dev/null
  - echo "$PROJECT_SSH_KEY"
  - ssh-add <(echo "$PROJECT_SSH_KEY")
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
      ##
  ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
  ##
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

  ##
  ## Optionally, if you will be using any Git commands, set the user name and
  ## and email.
  ##
  #- git config --global user.email "user@example.com"
  #- git config --global user.name "User name"
```

I get  this out put

> Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (4745a6f3)
>         on Allence-Tunisie-docker-runner sH47eTgb
>       Using Docker executor with image ntfactory/ci-tool:0.0.2 ...
>       Pulling docker image ntfactory/ci-tool:0.0.2 ...
>       Using docker image sha256:7fe7b170806f6846271eec23b41c4f79202777f62c0d7a32165dc41722900979
>   for ntfactory/ci-tool:0.0.2 ...
>       Running on runner-sH47eTgb-project-11060727-concurrent-0 via a732493b4b94...
>       Cloning repository...
>       Cloning into '/builds/allence-tunisie/e-formation'...
>       Checking out 0a6b48ef as feat/gitlab-ci...
>       Skipping Git submodules setup
>       Checking cache for default...
>       No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
>       Successfully extracted cache
>       $ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
>       /usr/bin/ssh-agent
>       $ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
>       Agent pid 12
>       $ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
>       $ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
>       Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format
>       ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

even though i tried  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add
- > /dev/null   i get  this error

> Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format

Comment: could you solve the error?

Comment: yes in fact the problem was with the ssh key

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This error happens when the private key in $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is malformed, you can easily test it locally if you add some random characters in it. In particular, it happens on Travis-CI when you just copy & paste the private key into the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable in the online form. It has to do with the new line characters after and before the -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----, -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- blocks.  For this reason, I use base64 encoding to make sure the key is formatted properly.

try this:

- Encode your private RSA key

  cat my_private_key | base64 -w0
- Add the base64 string to your project variables.
- Use it in your .gitlab-ci.yml

> ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d)

*https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_15038961*

Comment: did you copy the answer from here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_15038961  ???

if so you should add the source...

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/-/issues/1#note_16652372 this worked for me.

Answer (score 38):

If you have protected the variable then you need to have a protected branch. As mentioned in the variables settings - "They can be protected by only exposing them to protected branches or tags."

Comment: you save my day :)

Comment: In my case I was accidentally creating unprotected tags from main. This failed as my variables are protected. To fix this I went into Settings -> Repository -> Protected tags.

Comment: Scrolled right past this but it solved it for me! To check if this is happening you can also do a simple `wc -c` check which will show length 0 if the variable is inaccessible.

Comment: This helped a lot, even more than the accepted answer, tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

1. Generate ssh key [info about generation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#generate-an-ssh-key-pair)

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "<comment>"
```

2. Encode **PRIVATE_KEY**

```
cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa | base64 -w0
# OR
echo "-----BEGIN OPENSSH..." | base64 -w0
```

3. On gitlab, go to your *repository > settings > CI/CD > Variables* and add your variable with encoded value (also you can switch "protected variable flag")
4. In you .gitlab-ci.yml add decoding pipe

```
- ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_KEY" | base64 -d)
```

5. That's all.

But if you will have *"Permission denied, please try again."* error after all - try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74249524/8410290)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/-/issues/1#note_15038961) on GitLab's bug tracker, the issue can arise when carriage return characters (`\r`) are added to the variable (a.k.a. "secret"). This can be worked around by piping to `tr -d "\r"` to delete these characters, leaving the SSH key correctly formed.

An example in your CI would be:

```sh
ssh-add <(echo "${SSH_priv_key_b64}" | base64 --decode | tr -d "\r")
```

Note that base 64 encoding is necessary to use an SSH key with the "masked" and "protected" properties.

Answer (score 0):

For me I protected branch and tags , and then I finally did it without any errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that they have fixed the error. This is the new way to do it.

```
  ##
  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  ## without extra base64 encoding.
  ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  ##

  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
```

Answer (score 0):

The error I got was similar as above ones. However none of above works on my case. After I tried several times, I noticed the file is empty when my pipeline was running. Considering that I made my secrets only exposed to protected branches or protected tags, I went /-/settings/repository and added my target branches. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error from a silly mistake!- in my GitLab project settings, the `Type` for my variable was set to `File` instead of `Variable`.

And so, changing the `Type` from `File` to `Variable` fixed this for me.

Answer (score -1):

You must gen RSA key not OPENSSH Key. Use param "-m PEM" (ssh-keygen -m PEM) to generate RSA Key will start with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and end with -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Nope, that's not true.